# If data doesn't exist add to bottom of list

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Basically I'm working on a excel document which copies values from this workbook into another if they match. So if they have the same ID and a "yes" then a field is updated. However in some instances it may be that the ID doesn't exist in the workbook im copying to, but if there is a "yes" I would like to add it to the next empty row.

Below is what I have so far

```
Dim fpath As String
Dim owb As Workbook
Dim thisone As String
Dim Siteref(1000) As String, siteref2(1000) As String, sitename(1000) As String, sitename2(1000) As String



fpath = "my file path"


Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath) 'open location and file

Dim Master As Worksheet 'declare both
Dim Slave As Worksheet


Set Slave = owb.Worksheets("Schedule") 'sheet in workbook im copying too
Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary") 'sheet from workbook im in

For i = 1 To 1000 '(the slave sheet) 'for first 1000 cells
For j = 1 To 1000 '(the master sheet)

If Master.Cells(j, 2).Value = "" Then
GoTo lastline
End If ' if ID cell is blank jump to last line

   If Master.Cells(j, 2).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 1).Value And Master.Cells(j, 65).Value = "Yes" Then
       Slave.Cells(i, 4).Value = Master.Cells(j, 18).Value 'If the ID equals that in the slave sheet and there is a yes ticked the copy address

  End If

lastline:

Next
Next


MsgBox ("Data Transfer Successful")




Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary").Delete 'delete sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ThisWorkbook.Save
ThisWorkbook.Close 'save and close it
```

Comment: First of all: This use of GoTo makes me cringe... In VBA, you should use GoTo's only for error handling. For the task: Swap the master and slave loop, that way, you will look at one master entry and search through the slave sheet with it. If you reach the slave limit (j = 1000) and no match was found, append the master entry (if i,65 is yes) to the end of the slave sheet. If you find a match, break the current slave loop (exit for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this one a try and let me know if it works. I wrote it "blind" without testing. So, I am not entirely sure it will work:

```
Dim bolFound As Boolean
Dim lngLastRow As Long

Dim fpath As String
Dim owb As Workbook

Dim Master As Worksheet 'declare both
Dim Slave As Worksheet

fpath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath) 'open location and file

Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary") 'sheet from workbook im in
Set Slave = owb.Worksheets("Schedule") 'sheet in workbook im copying too
'
lngLastRow = Slave.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
For j = 1 To 1000 '(the master sheet)
    bolFound = False
    For i = 1 To 1000 '(the slave sheet) 'for first 1000 cells
        If Trim(Master.Cells(j, 2).Value2) = vbNullString Then Exit For 'if ID cell is blank jump to last line
        If Master.Cells(j, 2).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 1).Value And _
            Master.Cells(j, 65).Value = "Yes" Then
                Slave.Cells(i, 4).Value = Master.Cells(j, 18).Value 'If the ID equals that in the slave sheet and there is a yes ticked the copy address
                bolFound = True
        End If
    Next
    If bolFound = False And _
        Master.Cells(j, 65).Value = "Yes" Then
            Slave.Cells(lngLastRow, 4).Value = Master.Cells(j, 18).Value  'adding the new entry to the list
            lngLastRow = lngLastRow + 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox ("Data Transfer Successful")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary").Delete 'delete sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ThisWorkbook.Save
ThisWorkbook.Close 'save and close it
```

Comment: hi, thanks for this.. it doesn't seem to be adding the master.cells(j, 18).value however when I replaced it with just "hello" it seems to add it? & Also the fpath wasn't the active workbook it was a separate workbook I am writing too. 
Thanks

Comment: hi again @Ralph I added And _ Master.Cells(j, 65).Value = "Yes" to if bolfound = false and it works but only adds the last one, so if there's multiple it will only add the bottom value, is there a way for it to add all of them? Thanks.

Comment: I changed the code to reflect your addition. Also, I increased `lngLastRow` by one after an addition. Like this it should be able to add more than one to the end. Otherwise, it is constantly overwriting the same row.

Answer (score 0):

NOT tested.

```
Dim fpath As String
Dim owb As Workbook
Dim thisone As String
Dim Siteref(1000) As String, siteref2(1000) As String, sitename(1000) As String, sitename2(1000) As String
Dim lastRow As Long

fpath = "my file path"
Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath) 'open location and file

Dim Master As Worksheet 'declare both
Dim Slave As Worksheet

Set Slave = owb.Worksheets("Schedule") 'sheet in workbook im copying to
Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary") 'sheet from workbook im in

For i = 1 To 1000 '(the slave sheet) 'for first 1000 cells
    For j = 1 To 1000 '(the master sheet)

        If Master.Cells(j, 2).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If ' if ID cell is blank jump to last line

        If Master.Cells(j, 2).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 1).Value And Master.Cells(j, 65).Value = "Yes" Then
            'If the ID equals that in the slave sheet and there is a yes ticked the copy address
            Slave.Cells(i, 4).Value = Master.Cells(j, 18).Value
        End If

        If Master.Cells(j, 65).Value = "Yes" Then
            lastRow = Slave.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            'if yes found, copy value
            Slave.Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = Master.Cells(j, 18).Value
        End If
    Next
Next

MsgBox ("Data Transfer Successful")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tbl_Primary").Delete 'delete sheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ThisWorkbook.Save
ThisWorkbook.Close 'save and close it
```